# Move Magento "Store View Name" to "Store Name"

Tags: adminhtml, multistore, store-view

we setup three store Store View Name's a long time ago when this should have been Store Name's.

We are now busy rolling out multi-language and this is where I discovered the mistake.

Is there an easy way (and how) to move a Store View Name to a Store Group Name (1 up in the hierarchy)

```
Website             Store Group       Store View
------------------------------------------------
www.domain.com      domain.com        store1_NL
www.domain.com      domain.com        store2_NL
```

becomes

```
www.domain.com  store1      NL  
www.domain.com  store2      NL
...
www.domain.com  store2      EN
www.domain.com  store2      DE
etc
```

Thx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename it via the admin.

> Admin > System > Manage Stores

1. Create a new Store Group Name
2. Then open the Store View and assign to the new Store Group Name